# How do I get django 1.5 tests to use mysql?

Tags: mysql, django, testing

My database settings are

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME': 'foo',
...
```

When I run "django-admin.py test ..." a MySQL database called **test_foo** gets created and subsequently destroyed but it does not get populated during the tests.

If I open a shell within a test, I can access created objects using the Django models but the created MySQL database does not contain them.

I want the tests to use MySQL in case there are MySQL specific problems but I can't see any obvious way to do this.

I assume that the database is currently being created in memory and I can't see how to easily work out what database is being used. I'm assuming it's not MySQL because I can't see it with MySQL admin tools.

It would be nice if I could direct the tests to use the MySQL database they already create (test_foo) and back again to the current database (sqlite in memory?) so that if a MySQL specific problem is suspected I can reproduce it using the tests.

Does anyone know how I can control this behavior (hopefully without specializing my own test runner)?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the *multiple settings files* chapter in ***Two scoops of Django*** and split your settings files, each to use different db engine. Then use settings option:

```
django-admin.py test --settings=project.settings_test
django-admin.py test --settings=project.settings_test_mysql
```

Please refer to [this repo](https://github.com/twoscoops/django-twoscoops-project), for how the settings files are handled.

**--UPDATE--**

This is how test `settings_test` might look like:

```
from .settings import *

DEBUG = False
TEMPLATE_DEBUG = DEBUG

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME':   ':memory:',
        'USER': '',
        'PASSWORD': '',
        'HOST': '',
        'PORT': '',
    }
}

SOUTH_TESTS_MIGRATE = False
```

and similary for mysql, just use mysql db settings instead.

Comment: Thanks for the response but splitting the settings file does not help unless I can put something into the settings file to force the test suite to use the mysql database it creates... and if I can do that, I don't need a special test settings file.

Comment: @PaulWhipp Sorry I might misunderstood the question, you mean you can't change settings at all?